# Public IP assigned to an Azure VM with forced tunneling over ExpressRoute

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

can someone explain how the routing associated with a Public IP assigned to a ARM based Azure VM is influenced by forced tunnelling of a VNET to an ExpressRoute connection?

Is the machine still able reach the internet via it's Public IP or forced down the ExpressRoute when attempting to reach something off the 0.0.0.0/0?

Answer (score 1):

Azure VMs don't need a public IP Address to access the internet, they need a public IP so that you can connect to it from the internet and even with force tunnelling they will still be the case. With force tunnelling internet traffic initiated from the VM will be forced on premise.

you can test this by creating two VMs one with a public IP and one without, connect to the VM with the public IP and use it to RDP to the VM without the public IP and test Internet access.

as long as your Vnet, NSGs and name resolution are configured correctly things should work as described.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. I understand the use case for a Public IP but wanted to better understand how a Public IP influences the routing when a 0.0.0.0/0 route was used to point to an ExpressRoute. I think that you've confirmed that the traffic would still be routed via the ExpressRoute even with a public IP address assigned to a VM.

Answer (score 0):

As Micheal mentioned, the VM don't need a public IP address to access the internet.

If you have an ExpressRoute connection between your on-premises network and Azure, you can enable BGP to propagate routes from your on-premises network to Azure. These BGP routes are used in the same way as system routes and user defined routes in each Azure subnet. Forced tunneling is configured through BGP.
If you have advertise default routes (0.0.0.0/0) that will **block** all internet connectivity to virtual machines deployed within a virtual network and **route all traffic out through the ExpressRoute circuit**.
So the default routes (0.0.0.0/0) will route all the VM’s traffic out through the ExpressRoute circuit.

**Note** that if you advertise default routes, we will force traffic to services offered over public peering (such as Azure storage and SQL DB) back to your premises. You will have to configure your routers to return traffic to Azure through the public peering path or over the internet.

More information about ExpressRoute, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/expressroute-faqs/

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.
Best Regards,